# printf("%d\n", 1000000001) cause Segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I do not know why, gcc version 4.9.2 (Ubuntu 4.9.2-10ubuntu13 x86_64)

```
Breakpoint 1, convertToTitle (n=1000000001) at excel_sheet_column_title.c:14
14      printf("%d\n", n);
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400697 in convertToTitle (n=1000000001) at excel_sheet_column_title.c:14
14      printf("%d\n", n);
(gdb) p n
$1 = 1000000001
```

The complete code of the function, just called the function with 1000000001 in the main function:

```
char *convertToTitle(int n)
{
    int mod, idx, last = n / 26 + 1;
    char str[last], *title, *tp;

    printf("%d\n", n);

    idx = last;
    while (n > 26) {
        mod = n % 26;
        if (mod > 0) {
            str[--idx] = mod - 1 + 'A';
        } else if (mod == 0) {
            str[--idx] = 'Z';
            n -= 1;
        }
        n /= 26;
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        str[--idx] = n - 1 + 'A';
    }

    title = (char *)malloc((last - idx + 1) * sizeof(char));
    tp = title;
    for (; idx < last; idx++) {
        *tp++ = str[idx];
    }
    *tp = '\0';

    return title;
}
```

Comment: You mind creating an [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The errror must be somwhere else. Probably a memory overwrite of some kind. (n=1000000001 is *suspect*, to say the least)

Comment: `char str[last]` - for n = 1000000001 you're probably overflowing your stack. So stop blaming the poor `printf` ...

Comment: @dragosht what is the right size, or max size?

Comment: @dbay In Linux you can check it with `ulimit -s` ...

Comment: If `n < 0`, code has many problems.  Suggest use `unsigned n` or cope with negative numbers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `last` is very large. Move it outside of local function (or mark it static) to avoid segfault.

As an alternative (and correct) solution, calculate correct value of last.

(I think you wanted log<sub>26</sub>n + 1)

> 26<sup>last</sup> >= n
> last = log<sub>26</sub>n

```
last = ceil(log(n) / log(26)) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Weak calculation of needed buffer size for `str[]` resulted in an excessively large array size `last` of `1000000001/26 + 1`.  This array size was unsupportable as coded as a local variable.

What is needed is a much smaller array about `log26(n)`.

There is little need to "right-size" the buffer per various values of `int n`.  Simply use a constant size that works for `INT_MAX`.

As the bit size of an `int` is about `log2(INT_MAX)+1`,

```
#include <limits.h>
#define ABOUT_LOG2_26 4.7
#define BUF26_SIZE ((int)(sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/ABOUT_LOG2_26 + 2))

char *convertToTitle(int n) {
  char str[BUF26_SIZE];
  ...
  // Also cope with negative values of n
  if (n < 0) Handle_Error();
```